# rsync in Expect script

Tags: linux, scripting, rsync, expect

```
     #!/usr/bin/expect -f
        #set timeout 25
        spawn rsync root@14.12.123.82:'/usr/backups /usr/backup-scripts /root/test/' /root/
        expect "root@14.12.123.82's password: $"
        #send "\$xxxxxx\n"
        #expect "\\$ $
```

What is wrong with the above script i get an error saying invalid rsync options

Answer (score 1):

From `man rsync`, this is the new syntax for multiple files:

```
rsync -av host:file1 :file2 host:file{3,4} /dest/
```

The old syntax you are using should still work in the command line, but try this in `spawn`:

```
spawn rsync root@14.12.123.82:/usr/backups :/usr/backup-scripts :/root/test/ /root/
```

Comment: Yes I did and it worked fine. Note that I don't have the same setup as you. Also take a look here: http://rootprompt.org/article.php3?article=5760 - there are examples on how to do it which might work for you.